# Is there a way to escape characters with Saxon HE 9.5.1.2? xsl processor

Tags: xml, regex, xslt-2.0, saxon, altova

I'm writing an xsl:analyze-string to look at dates.  When I run it with an Altova processor, my xslt executes without a problem.  However when I run the same xslt, on the Saxon HE 9.5.1.2 processor, the xslt fails, citing "Syntax error at char 10 in regular expression: Escape character '/' not allowed".  If a forward slash escaped by \ is not allowed, is there an alternative way to escape the character with the Saxon processor?

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="/document/body//td[@class='date']/text()" regex="^(\d{{2}})(\/)(\d{{2}})(\/)(\d{{4}})$">
```

I'm going to try it with:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="/document/body//td[@class='date']/text()" regex="^(\d{{2}})(.)(\d{{2}})(.)(\d{{4}})$">  , but it seems like we should be able to use the normal escape.
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Forwards slash is not a special character (metacharacter) in regular expressions so it doesn't need to be escaped. The XSD/XPath regular expression dialect, unlike many others, does not allow characters to be escaped unless they actually need to be escaped - the reason for this is that it effectively reserves these escape sequences for future use. A processor that allows forwards slash to be escaped is non-conformant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the slash does not need escaping so try `regex="^(\d{{2}})(/)(\d{{2}})(/)(\d{{4}})$"`.